# Python - Mapping Strings onto A Boolean Array

Tags: python, string, numpy, boolean, mapping

I have a boolean array like such

```
bool_arr = [True, True, False]
```

And I want to map two Strings onto each boolean value

```
string_arr = ['r', 'r, 'k']
```

How would I map this using numpy?

Comment: Those are `numpy` arrays?

Comment: Yes, I've just shown them like this for shorthand

Comment: "map two Strings onto each boolean value" -- don't know what that means. Map True to "r" and False to "k"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectorized approaches using indexing -

```
bool_arr = np.array([True, True, False]) # Input boolean array
strings = np.array(['k','r']) # Input array of strings for mapping

out = np.take(strings, bool_arr)
out = np.take(strings, bool_arr.astype(int))
out = strings[bool_arr.astype(int)]
```

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if we need to choose between just two strings -

```
np.where(bool_arr, 'r','k')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> bool_arr = [True, True, False]
>>> ['r' if x else 'k' for x in bool_arr]
['r', 'r', 'k']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `numpy.vectorize` method:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([True, True, False])
mapping = ('k','r')
result = np.vectorize(lambda i:mapping[i])(x)
```

which gives:

```
>>> result
array(['r', 'r', 'k'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```